# Прогресс бар при получении данных по API

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Есть сайт, обращаемся к нему по api и протоколу GET.
В ответ приходит много информации, это занимает время.
Нужно добавить прогресс бар, который отображал бы прогресс получения данных.
Как это можно сделать ?

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://cloud.roistat.com/api/v1/project/integration/order/list?project=44444444&key=4444444444"

payload = "{\"filters\":{\"and\":[[\"creation_date\",\">\",\"2020-06-02T21:00:00+0000\"],[\"creation_date\",\"<\",\"2020-07-01T21:00:00+0000\"]]},\"extend\":[\"visit\"],\"limit\":30000,\"offset\":0}"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

data = r.json()

with open('roi.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Я нашел библиотеку с прогресс барами tqdm, но так и не понял, как ее присобачить к requests

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573483/progress-bar-while-download-file-over-http-with-requests/37573701

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)

size = r.headers.get('content-length',0)
load = 0
data = b''
for chunk in r.iter_content(8192):
    data += chunk
    load += len(chunk)
    sys.stdout.write('\r%d/%d' % (load, size))
    sys.stdout.flush()

data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Итог такой:

"""4950/1784""""

выдал это после получения всех данных - то есть этот прогресс бар не обновлялся в процессе загрузки, а просто выдал итоговое значение после уже загрузки, причем по итогу неверный размер вышел - 4950/1784

Comment: похоже сжато gzip - вы не узнаете размер файла пока его не загрузите.

4950 - это не большой файл. 8192 замените на 1024 - тогда скрол у вас дернется 4 раза

Comment: хук врятли можно вставить  в requests чтоб оценивать размер данных до распаковки gzip

Comment: До этого качал лишь огрызок данных. Сейчас вот скачал все. Параметр size = 0, видимо данные и вправду сжаты, раз он размер не может определить. Прогресс бар работает, однако он начинает обновляться только после того, как все данные скачаются - то есть  он не отображает сам прогресс получения данных. Я так понимаю, что простым методом эту всю историю не решить

Comment: аа, точно, буферизованный вывод питона... сейчас добавлю

Comment: получается так:
Size до сих пор равен нулю, прогресс бар имеет, например, такой вид ""1435741/0"".
После запроса  ""r = req...... ""   ожидание где-то минуту.
Потом начинает только бежать прогресс бар.
Может во время этого ожидания сервер просто пакует данные ?
А скачиваение в итоге происходит быстро и прогресс бар по итогу все верно считает, ну кроме параметра Size

Comment: уверен что так оно и есть. если хотите убедиться, то сделайте такой запрос  браузером и посмотрите тайминги на вкладке network.

Comment: проблема json в том что он пакуется и разпаковывается всегда целым куском.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за помощь !

Comment: после упаковки сервер уже знает размер посылки, но он отправляет ответ без размера для того чтоб клиент не отвалился до начала пересылки